# Is fullscreen really better than windowed mode in a Direct3D 12 application?

Tags: c++, graphics, direct3d12

I'm trying to learn Direct3D 12 to do some simple 3D graphics for fun.

I've heard that pure fullscreen is the way to go for maximum fps, but now that I'm testing it, fullscreen seems way, way worse than windowed mode.

For example, a static color on a `WS_BORDER` window (with fullscreen size), and `Windowed` set to `TRUE` in the `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FULLSCREEN_DESC`, can be rendered (with triple-buffering) at about 5000 fps on my computer.

On the other hand, a static color on a `WS_POPUP` window, `Windowed` set to `FALSE` in the `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FULLSCREEN_DESC` and also `IDXGISwapChain3::SetFullscreenState(TRUE, nullptr)` called, only renders (with triple-buffering) at about 3000 fps.

Should this be the case or am I missing something?

Comment: `Is fullscreen really better than windowed mode` Yes. It really is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The story of "fullscreen" for Direct3D is a complex one, and from the other comments/answers in this thread continues be a confused one.

For DirectX 12 on Windows 10, there **is no FullScreen Exclusive mode (FSE)**. When you use `SetFullscreenState` with either of the modern `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD` or `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL` effect modes then use are really using **emulated Fullscreen Exclusive mode (eFSE)**. DirectX 12 does not support using the the older 'blt-style' effects `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD` or `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_SEQUENTIAL`.

If you run with a borderless window that is maximized to cover the entire screen in "windowed mode", it's the same performance as using "eFSE".

There are some 3rd party video card vendor APIs and scenarios that require you use "fullcreen mode" rather than "windowed mode", so in those cases there's a difference.

The other issue is if you are trying to change the *display mode* vs. using the *native resolution*. The performance impacts here are the "pixel-fill' rate for the render target size. There are techniques for scaling performance by rendering to an 'offscreen' render target size and then scaling that up to the native resolution of a backbuffer vs. changing the display mode to try to reduce the size of the backbuffer.

See [The Care and Feeding of Modern Swap Chains](https://walbourn.github.io/care-and-feeding-of-modern-swapchains/) and [Demystifying Fullscreen Optimizations](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/demystifying-full-screen-optimizations/).